# Create a MahApps.Metro custom dialog and displaying it - Step by step howto please

Tags: wpf, dialog, mahapps.metro, customdialog

using VS 2013 and MahApps. I want to create a simple totally custion dialog, and am lost.

I would like to use XAML, but only code is also OK. The examples and documentations are very limited. Anyone can walk me through this?

Thanks!

Comment: What did you try so far? Does this short sample help? http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/Blogs/48620/wpf-mahapps-custom-login.aspx

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change MahApps.Metro dialog content template width?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30751663/how-to-change-mahapps-metro-dialog-content-template-width)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's already an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30797630/4535033) from MahApps author.
He suggested to replace the dialog template with a style.

Also, there's a [SimpleChildWindow](https://github.com/punker76/MahApps.Metro.SimpleChildWindow) project that he's supporting. It's not totally custom but surely simple.