# Overwrite button's style in a Mahapps Metro dialog

Tags: c#, wpf, mahapps.metro

I want to rewrite the color of the buttons in an Mahapps Metro dialog with a custom one (not by using Accent color). I am mostly interested in changing the color of the button that is displayed while being clicked. This is the default style of the [button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/btBaD.jpg) when is being clicked.

App.xaml:

```
<ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Controls.xaml"/>
<ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Fonts.xaml"/>
<ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Colors.xaml"/>
<ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/BaseLight.xaml"/>
<ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/Crimson.xaml"/>
<ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/Blue.xaml"/>
<ResourceDictionary Source="Styles.xaml" />
```

MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Grid>
    <Button
        Content="Open Metro Dialog"
        Click="Button_Click"
        Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle}"
        />
</Grid>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
public partial class MainWindow : WindowBase
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageDialogResult dialogResult = await this.ShowMessageAsync("Close window", "Are you sure you want to close the window?", MessageDialogStyle.Affirmative);

        if (dialogResult == MessageDialogResult.Affirmative)
        {
           this.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

What i tried so far:

1. Rewrite the Mahapps Metro color with key 'BlackBrush' (this one is
   being used as background color for the button) with a custom one;
2. Rewrite the control template for the button.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: What it doesn't work?

Comment: I want the background color of the button to be different from the default one (the one displayed in picture) when i press the button. I am not able to overwrite the style of the Mahapps Metro dialog to achieve the desired effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to work on the style of the Metro dialog control. You can find it [here](https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro/blob/336f7dfc4bda2d0eba8aa270737ca3c11d45128c/src/MahApps.Metro/MahApps.Metro/Themes/Dialogs/MessageDialog.xaml). To use it, add

```
xmlns:Dialogs="clr-namespace:MahApps.Metro.Controls.Dialogs;assembly=MahApps.Metro"
```

then proceed to follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30751663/how-to-change-mahapps-metro-dialog-content-template-width) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33292197/how-to-change-mahapps-metro-dialog-content-using-styles-remix)