# How to change MahApps.Metro dialog style?

Tags: wpf, xaml, modal-dialog, controltemplate, mahapps.metro

I would like to change the style of a message dialog. I used this: [How to change MahApps.Metro dialog content template width?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30751663/how-to-change-mahapps-metro-dialog-content-template-width)

I want different styles for some dialogues. How can I change the style of a single dialog? I tried to do it with the `CustomResourceDictionary` property. But this has no effect.

```cs
var Style = (Style) Application.Current.Resources["NewCustomDialogStyle"];
var mySettings = new MetroDialogSettings()
    {
        CustomResourceDictionary = Style.Resources
    };
```

When I override the MessageDialog style everything is fine

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Dialog:MessageDialog}" BasedOn="{StaticResource NewCustomDialogStyle}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You need create new style based on Mahapps style. You can find it here: 
https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro/blob/336f7dfc4bda2d0eba8aa270737ca3c11d45128c/src/MahApps.Metro/MahApps.Metro/Themes/Dialogs/MessageDialog.xaml

And then use it only for whatever you want dialog