# Custom Popup validation message in Mahapps

Tags: c#, wpf, mahapps.metro

I'm creating a WPF application using Mahapps and I am trying to change the popup message when  I enter a wrong value (like the photo below)
I would like to change "Value 'e' could not be converted."

[image: Example]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know `Mahapps.Metro` to much but **override a Metro Window style** seems sufficient enough.

For example, one of this question [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30751663/how-to-change-mahapps-metro-dialog-content-template-width)

```
<Style x:Key="newDialogStyle" BasedOn="{StaticResource MetroDialogStyle}" TargetType="{x:Type Dialogs:BaseMetroDialog}">
     <!-- ur design of Control Template -->
</Style>

<Dialogs:CustomDialog Style="{StaticResource newDialogStyle}" Title="Custom Dialog which is awaitable">
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock  Height="30" 
                    Text="This dialog allows arbitrary content. You have to close it yourself by clicking the close button below."
                    TextWrapping="Wrap"
                    Foreground="{DynamicResource AccentColorBrush}" />
        <Button Content="Close Me!"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Dialogs:CustomDialog>
```