# How to change ShowMessageAsync flow direction to "Right to Left"?

Tags: wpf, mahapps.metro

Is there any way to change Mahapps messagebox window (ShowMessageAsync)'s flow direction to Right to left ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set the `FlowDirection` for the whole `MetroWindow` and all childrens.

```
FlowDirection="RightToLeft"
```

[image]

If you only want to set this to `MessageDialog` then you can change the style e.g. in your App.xaml like this

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Dialog:MessageDialog}"
        BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Dialog:BaseMetroDialog}}">
    <Setter Property="FlowDirection" Value="RightToLeft" />
</Style>
```

So all message dialogs will get this style.

[image]

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Overwriting the style should do it,

see: [How to change MahApps.Metro dialog content template width?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30751663/how-to-change-mahapps-metro-dialog-content-template-width)

The answer has a nice little tutorial.

Comment: please summarize the link here.